# Manually set IntelliSense include directories (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, intellisense, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Vistual Studio Community 2019 to build (CMake) and debug C++ [code](https://github.com/otland/forgottenserver). 
Compilation and debugging both happen in WSL and work fine.
The problem is IntelliSense, which keeps complaining that it's not able to find the necessary headers.

Visual Studio is able to zip all necessary headers from the WSL and download it.
I even checked the local copy folders to see if they were correct. And they are.

I even tried to mess around with CppProperties.json in order to point it to the downloaded headers (which should be done regardless), but with no success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/intellisense-enhancements-for-cpp-open-folder-and-cmake/) makes some help?

Comment: Hello, @LanceLi-MSFT. Thank you for reaching out.
It seems to be a related issue, but not what's happening to me, unfortunately. I've got the red squiggles! x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening.

IntelliSense needs the "full path" to the header file you're including.
For instance, in my case, instead of using

```
#include <lua.hpp>
```

I had to use

```
#include <lua5.2/lua.hpp>
```

In order for it to work you have to have things set up as I described above. Feel free to comment if you're having trouble. :)

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)

Comment: Sorry, @LanceLi-MSFT I had to wait 48h to do so and forgot it. Thank you for reminding me!